# Force capitalised input to title case in CSS using text-transform

Tags: css, string, text

I'm creating a theme for a CMS, and only have the ability to change the CSS associated with the page (no Javascript, PHP, etc).

Is there a way to change this list of users that we have:

> JOHN SMITH
>  DAVID JONES
>  ...

into proper title case (John Smith, etc) using CSS?

`text-transform: lowercase;` works ok (john smith, etc) but `text-transform: capitalize;` does nothing (remains capitalised).

---

As requested, the HTML is:

```
<tr> [...] <td class="cell c1">ALEXANDER MULLER</td> [...] </tr>
<tr> [...] <td class="cell c1">JOHN SMITH</td> [...] </tr>
```

And the CSS is:

```
td {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the html and css that you're using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`text-transform: capitalize;` only modifies the first letter of each word, so if the first letter of a word is already capitalized, text-transform skips that word.

Example:

`JoHN smith` will become `JoHN Smith`

There is no way to do title-casing using only CSS unless all of your words are all lowercase.

Comment: Ah, well - to everybody, thanks for taking the time to respond anyway.

Comment: This answer is correct if your solution can only use CSS. But if the context is a Wordpress theme, you could easily achieve the desired result by adding `strtolower( $text )` in the PHP template then using `text-transform : capitalize;`. This will generate lowercase markup that you can then convert to title case with css.

Answer (score 8):

We can use a trick to do it. But watch for browser compatibility.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

```
p{
  text-transform: lowercase;
 }

p:first-letter{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Eg:

this is some text. 
     This is SOME text.
     this IS some TEXT.

Output -> This is some text

Answer (score 6):

What your're experiencing is how it works. This is from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#caps-prop):

> "**capitalize** Puts the first
>   character of each word in uppercase;
>   other characters are unaffected."

Now, you can do (I'm assuming you have a list with list item `<li>` tags:

```
li:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Along with your lowercase of the li, but in combination that will only affect the first words of each line, so you get:

```
John smith
David jones
```

I don't believe there's a pure CSS solution for you here. This is tricky because of names like John McCain, Oscar de la Hoya, John Smith PhD, Jane Smith MD, and people who prefer lowercase like danah boyd or e.e. cummings. There's always exceptions when you try to use Title Case. These exceptions will cause you headaches. If you don't have control over the content, the content will give you headaches.

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, the only way I've ever got this working is with the use of javascript. As the other answers state, the capitalize transform doesn't do the trick.

I think that if this is a requirement then you'll have to figure out a way to sanitize the names upstream. Either capitalize them correctly, or convert them to lower case so that the CSS transform will work as expected.

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue numerous times when the text comes in all uppercase from a CMS or database. What I do is use jQuery .each function to iterate through the selected elements, apply a javascript toLowerCase method to each, then use CSS to set text-transform: capitalize.

Works every time!

Comment: I should have mentioned that this method will convert any and all text to title case. It will change things like "IBM" to "Ibm", or "McDonalds" to "Mcdonalds". In order to exclude those scenarios you will have to either use a regex qualifier and/or check each entry against a database or dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that *text-transform: capitalize* is working for me in IE, Chrome and FF for Windows:

http://www.tizag.com/cssT/text.php

What are you using to try it out in?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was about only the CSS way. Since most of the views are with models nowadays, this might help somebody.

```html
   <div style="text-transform: capitalize;">
      {{ person.firstName.toLowerCase() }}
   </div>
```